# Trying to interpret ANCOVA in R

Tags: r, lm, ancova

here's a brief overview of what I'm trying to do. The dataset I have was collected from an experiment that compared 3 conditions (control, group 1 and group 2) on performance. My first task was to compare if there's a diff between gr1 vs control. I did an independent t test for that and it was not significant (so no sig diff between group means?). My next task is to include a covariate. This covariate has two levels: high (scores range from 4 to 7) and low (scores range from 0 to 3). My code looks like this:

```
lm(performance ~ condition*covariate)
```

I did this for gr1 vs control. The output shows condition is significant, covariate is significant but the interaction isn't. I'm confused with why condition is now significant. I also ran the analysis with just performance ~ condition but that was not significant. Would anyone be able to dumb it down for me.

Comment: Recommend asking this on [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I try to help: In brief:
The aim of an ANCOVA is to remove the effect of the covariate on the target variable (condition in your case).
Assuming:

1. that your aim is to investigate the effect of group status (control,
   group1 and group2) on performance. -> Dependent variable =
   **performance**, Independent variable = (**condition** = group status).
2. The effect is not significant between control and group1 without the
   covariable (high/low).
3. But after including your covariate it is significant.
4. you have checked for the assumptions performing an ANCOVA.

I interpret your result as:
Your covariate is an important factor for your analysis. Interpretation of your findings should include the covariate.  And it is ok and good for your model that the interaction is not significant. With the interaction you check the homogeneity of the regression slopes (one of the assumptions for ANCOVA).